# Problem Copying Values to Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, fstream

I'm trying to make write a program that can take 81 integers from a text file, and add them to a multidimensional array.

I'm reading from a text file containing these integers:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 
55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81
```

This is the code that I'm using to do this

```
int main() 
{
    ifstream myFile; //ifstream object

    int num[8][8]; //multidimensional array
    int TempStorage[80]; //temporary storage for reading numbers off of text file
    int maybe; //no clue what this one does

    int i=0; //used for temp storage input
    int x=0; //used to copy values to multidimensional array

    myFile.open("numbers.txt"); //open document

    if(myFile.is_open()) //check if document is open
    {
        while(myFile >> maybe) //while numbers are still on document
        {
            TempStorage[i] = maybe; //input numbers into temporary array
            i++; //index 
        }
        myFile.close(); //close document

        for(int n=0;n<9;n++) //first loop to control first index n
        {
            for(int q=0;q<9;q++) //second loop to control second index q        
            {
                num[n][q] = TempStorage[x];//read numbers into multidimensional array
                x++;    
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I output all the values stored in the multidimensional array, I get the  following output. For some reason, it seems that the value of a previous index and the value of the first new index are equal.

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  10
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 28
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 37
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 46
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 55
55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 64
64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 73
73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 1
```

I have changed the conditions on my for loops to just about everything that I could think of. Is this just some woefully simple problem that I am overlooking or is it something else?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You have an off by one error in your for loops.

Comment: Instead of C arrays, use C++ arrays. So `std::array<std::array<int, 8> 8> num;` then you can do `for (size_t n = 0; n != num.size(); ++n) { for (size_t q = 0; q != num[n].size(); ++q) { ...` Also `TempStorage` should be a `std::vector<int>` and you should do `TempStorage.push_back(maybe);` otherwise you have undefined behavior depending on the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int n=0;n<9;n++)
```

Your multidimensional array has an [8] size, which means it can get from 0 to 7.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I thought my arrays were the correct size, but clearly not. Thanks!!